# Search substring in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string-matching, regex-negation, regex-group

I'm trying to search for a set of words, contained within an `ArrayList(terms_1pers)`, inside a string and, since the precondition is that before and after the search word there should be no letters, I thought of using expression regular.

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong using the matches operator. In the code reported, if the matching is not verified, it writes to an external file.

```
String url = csvRecord.get("url");
String text = csvRecord.get("review");
String var = null;
for(String term : terms_1pers)
{
   if(!text.matches("[^a-z]"+term+"[^a-z]"))
   {
      var="true";
   }
}
if(!var.equals("true"))
{
    bw.write(url+";"+text+"\n");
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you searching for?

Comment: matches returns true if the whole string matches the regexp. Read the javadoc to find out more, and learn what you should use instead. Also, don't use a string to represent boolean values. Use a boolean. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I would like to know if the expression contained in the matches command is correct. For example, to find `[^a-z]dog[^a-z]` is the setting correct?

Comment: @Gaetano the matches() method that you are using requires an exact match. in this case, "4dog5" is a match, but "a3dog3b" is not a match. look at my updated answer.

Comment: While @JeremyOwens is trying some mind-reading, it is you who should provide some actual examples which you expect to match `"..."+"dog"+"..."`, and some others you expect to not match. Then someone could provide input on what the `"..."`-s could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find regex matches, you should use the regex classes. Pattern and Matcher.

```
String term = "term";
ArrayList<String> a  = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("123term456"); //true
a.add("A123Term5"); //false
a.add("term456"); //true
a.add("123term"); //true
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^A-Za-z]*(" + term + ")[^A-Za-z]*$");
for(String text : a) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1) );
         //since the term you are adding is the second matchable portion, you're looking for group(1)
    }
    else System.out.println("No match for: " + term);
}
```

}

In the example there, we create an instance of a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html to find matches in the text you are matching against.

Note that I adjusted the regex a bit. The choice in this code excludes all letters A-Z and the lowercase versions from the initial matching part. It will also allow for situations where there are no characters at all before or after the match term. If you need to have something there, use `+` instead of `*`. I also limited the regex to force the match to only contain matches for these three groups by using `^` and `$` to verify end the end of the matching text. If this doesn't fit your use case, you may need to adjust.

To demonstrate using this with a variety of different terms:

```
ArrayList<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();
terms.add("term");
terms.add("the book is on the table");
terms.add("1981 was the best year ever!");
ArrayList<String> a  = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("123term456");
a.add("A123Term5");
a.add("the book is on the table456");
a.add("1@#!231981 was the best year ever!9#");
for (String term: terms) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^A-Za-z]*(" + term + ")[^A-Za-z]*$");

    for(String text : a) {

        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
             System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1)  + " in " + text);
             //since the term you are adding is the second matchable portion, you're looking for group(1)
        }
        else System.out.println("No match for: " + term + " in " + text);
    }
}
```

Output for this is:
Found: term in 123term456
No match for: term in A123Term5
No match for: term in the book is on the table456....

In response to the question about having String term being case insensitive, here's a way that we can build a string by taking advantage of `java.lang.Character` to options for upper and lower case letters.

```
String term = "This iS the teRm.";
String matchText = "123This is the term.";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append("^[^A-Za-z]*(");
for (int i = 0; i < term.length(); i++) {
  char c = term.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isLetter(c))
    str.append("(" + Character.toLowerCase(c) + "|" + Character.toUpperCase(c) + ")");
  else str.append(c);
}
str.append(")[^A-Za-z]*$");

System.out.println(str.toString());


Pattern p = Pattern.compile(str.toString());
Matcher m = p.matcher(matchText);
if (m.find()) System.out.println("Found!");
else System.out.println("Not Found!");
```

This code outputs two lines, the first line is the regex string that's being compiled in the Pattern. `"^[^A-Za-z]*((t|T)(h|H)(i|I)(s|S) (i|I)(s|S) (t|T)(h|H)(e|E) (t|T)(e|E)(r|R)(m|M).)[^A-Za-z]*$"` This adjusted regex allows for letters in the term to be matched regardless of case. The second output line is "Found!" because the mixed case term is found within matchText.

Comment: in my case what you wrote in the `term` variable is a text string (for example "the book is on the table"). is it the same?

Comment: you should be fine to insert a text string there. I just tested the code using "the book is on the table" as the value of String term, and it worked.

Comment: I edited the code to show using longer text string and looping through multiple items.

Comment: Thanks. to make homes insensitive what modification should I make?

Comment: to make terms case insensitive, you'll have to make the regex correctly. I'll edit the post with some new code.

Comment: New code is up showing how to build regex to be case insensitive. I hope these examples are sufficient to be applied to your use case and answer the question.

Comment: sorry for the umpteenth question. after identifying the substring in the text, how can I substitute the substring identified with a random character (for example \t)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194326/discussion-between-gaetano-and-jeremy-owens).

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to note:

- `matches` requires a full string match, so `[^a-z]term[^a-z]` will only match a string like `:term.`. You need to use `.find()` to find partial matches
- If you pass a literal string to a regex, you need to `Pattern.quote` it, or if it contains special chars, it will not get matched
- To check if a word has some pattern before or after *or* at the start/end, you should either use alternations with anchors (like `(?:^|[^a-z])` or `(?:$|[^a-z])`) or lookarounds, `(?<![a-z])` and `(?![a-z])`.
- To match any letter just use `\p{Alpha}` or - if you plan to match any Unicode letter - `\p{L}`.
- The `var` variable is more logical to set to Boolean type.

Fixed code:

```
String url = csvRecord.get("url");
String text = csvRecord.get("review");
Boolean var = false;
for(String term : terms_1pers)
{
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{L})" + Pattern.quote(term) + "(?!\\p{L})").matcher(text);
   // If the search must be case insensitive use
   // Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<!\\p{L})" + Pattern.quote(term) + "(?!\\p{L})").matcher(text); 
   if(!m.find())
   {
       var = true;
   }
}
if (!var) {
   bw.write(url+";"+text+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not consider the case where the start and end may contain letters
so adding .* at the front and end should solve your problem.

```
for(String term : terms_1pers)
{
   if( text.matches(".*[^a-zA-Z]+" + term + "[^a-zA-Z]+.*)" )  
   {
      var="true";
      break; //exit the loop
   }
}
if(!var.equals("true"))
{
    bw.write(url+";"+text+"\n");
}
```

Comment: Because with the `contain` it can happen that the substring I am looking for is included in another word, while I am interested in finding the single words in a text. For this reason I wanted to use regular expressions, that is to exclude the cases in which the letters before or after the terms (in the string text) I am searching for are a-z.

Comment: there is an error in the row where there is `matches` and in any case it doesn't work